# How do you instantiate Pages that have constructors in UWP?

Tags: dependency-injection, uwp

I want to use the Navigation feature in UWP.  Unfortunately, the argument to the **Navigate** method is a type, not an instance of a page.  It looks like the activation of this type is done behind the scenes.  I question the design decision, but my immediate problem is that all my MVVM forms are instantiated with the view model.  Typically I create pages using the Dependency Injection container.

How do you create pages in UWP when they're used with the **Navigate** method when those pages have DI constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you create pages in UWP when they're used with the `Navigate` method when those pages have DI constructors?

Instead trying to navigate to the page based on its type, you could set the `Content` of the `Frame` to an instance that you create yourself:

```
rootFrame.Content = new YourPage(yourDependency);
```

The other option is to make sure that all your pages have a default parameterless constructor and inject the dependencies somewhere else, for example in the OnNavigatedTo method as suggested by @Richard Zhang - MSFT.

Comment: I'm coming to the Conclusion that the Navigation architecture in UWP is just brain damaged.  It could be used in a quick hobby program, but it's completely missed the mark for a commercial application.

Comment: Yep, but i think in time it will get better.

Comment: @Going-gone Oddly, in **Xamarin.Forms** they use the instance of the page for navigation.  Solves the several problems I had trying to get this to work with just the page type as the parameter for navigation.

Comment: For anyone else that may happen on this question: the **Navigation architecture in UWP is not worth the effort to learn**.  I spent two days trying to get MVVM and DI to work with it and each problem solved created two new problems.  I finally chucked it out the window and wrote my own MVVM/DI navigator in a day.

Comment: @Quarkly Please share this custom navigator :P
I've been struggling with a multi tier menu with pivots in a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

In UWP, the navigation parameters of `Frame.Navigate` are `Type` rather than instances. This is really a design.

In fact, navigating in UWP doesn't require instances, as well as DI, and in general, if you need to combine `Page` and `ViewModel`, you can do this:

**1. Initialize `ViewModel` inside the page constructor**

*Frame*

```cs
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage));
```

*MyPage*

```cs
private MyViewModel vm;
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    vm = new MyViewModel();
}
```

**2. Initialize `ViewModel` by passing parameters when navigating**

*Frame*

```cs
var vm = new MyViewModel();
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage), vm);
```

*MyPage*

```cs
private MyViewModel vm;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Parameter!=null && e.Parameter is MyViewModel _vm)
    {
        vm = _vm;
        // do other things
    }
}
```

---

If you want to reuse pages, you can enable page caching, it will save the current page state (including `ViewModel`), and use the cache when you next navigate to the page, so you can avoid repeatedly creating `ViewModel`.

```cs
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this has to be one of the dumbest design decisions in the history of .NET.  Who's idea was this?  It files in the face of both DI and MVVM.  It also makes the Navigation architecture of UWP pretty much useless.

Comment: The parameter that goes onto the Navigation stack has to be the state of the view model, it can't be the newly constructed view model.  For example, I want to navigate to **UserView** with a user of **Fred**.  If I Navigate to **UserView** with a parameter of **UserViewModel**, then the virgin view model is put onto the stack and there's no place to store **Fred**, which is really the state I want pushed onto the stack.  Again, this strikes me as one of the poorest Navigation architectures I've run across.